# error: out of memory / the connection was reset

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am trying to do a massive select * { insert into..} on a php page using xampp (v 5.5.30) on windows (64bit, 4 Gb ram).

After a few minutes I however get either two error messages:

A) "the connection was reset" in the browsers, or sometimes:

B) "mysql_query(): (HY000/2008): Out of memory..." during the insertion query.

On both occasions the PHP script itself is halted even using the directive:

`ignore_user_abort(true);`

I can't figure out why this is happening. Things I tried so for:

1) added in my apache config file:

`<IfModule mpm_winnt_module> ThreadStackSize 8388608 </IfModule>` because in the error log I noticed the line at the time of the connection reset:

> [Mon Dec 07 13:01:23.540742 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2344:tid
>   504] AH00428: Parent: child process 4036 exited with status 3221225477
>   -- Restarting.
>
> [Mon Dec 07 12:09:39.584814 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1684:tid
>   528] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

It seems like this error is linked to my problem in some way. Changing the config file however did not help and the error still appears.

2) Changed php ini setting:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","750MB");
```

3) Removed all mysql cache using:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE
```

4) Set PHP timeout:

```
set_time_limit(60*60);
```

The error occurs after a few minutes already.

Additional note: the filesize of the table used in the main select-query (mytable.MYD) is 400Mb, of which I only use a few columns of in the select. Once the query is loaded in the PHP memory, before executing the while loop, the memory footprint is 60Mb (using memory_get_usage())

Any idea what I can do to solve this?

thanks

Comment: You don't seem to have done any research into where the problem is occurring, and haven't provided the relevant information to support any analysis of the problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to set execution time also.

set execution time to 0,it is functionally equivalent to turning the execution limit off completely:

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that didn't work; On top of my PHP page I have already set a larger time out : set_time_limit(60*60);. I should edit my main post to add it